# _.findWhere($scope.Tabs, {id: id, groupId: groupId}) not working

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to find a object where id= given id and groupId= given groupID.

i have tried this:

```
_.findWhere($scope.claimTabs, {id: id.claimId,groupId: id.groupId})
```

it is saying undefined.

Please suggest how to find an object where i am passing id and groupid params

Comment: Is this really an angular question?  Is that [tag:underscore.js]?

Comment: please show all relevant code.... for all we know you are trying to search an array that hasn't been returned from server yet and we have no idea where your `id` object comes from

Answer (score -1):

**You can change it by**

```
  var _exist = _.find($scope.claimTabs, function (item) {
          return item.claimId == id && item.groupId==groupid;
   });
```